# Default look up Behaviour Not Showing Recent searches

Tags: lookup, lookup-field

I have this Behaviour in my Dev Org that whenever I am an admin and I click on the Change owner (default OOTB feature) and click on the Look up, I can see this:

[image]

Questions

1. Where is this getting triggered? It isn't the recent search I tried searching for a different user and the default auto populated isn't changed.
2. This is actually not happening on my Other orgs , I am not sure what am I missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prepopulated list of users could include users that have previously been involved in ownership transfers for that particular record, users that belong to the same team or department as the current owner, or users who have been identified as potential owners based on their role and access level.

Additionally, Salesforce's intelligent data insights and algorithms may analyze previous ownership transfers, user behaviors, and other factors to provide personalized recommendations for potential new owners.

It is possible that your other orgs do not have enough information to provide you with these suggestions and they will appear after you transfer some records or add more possible owners (users) to the org

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!